# HTML/JavaScript: Sidebar expand/collapse button

Tags: javascript, html, button

So I'm using this "Color Admin Responsive Admin Template" (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0N89JMK) and I have a sidebar menu, and I have the expand/collapse button displaying, but the actual function is not working. I'm not sure exactly why it isn't working, I got the function from the template. I'm pretty new to JavaScript but I think everything that I needed to change on my specific HTML matches the function.

HTML

```
<!--sidebar left start-->
<!-- begin #sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    <!-- begin sidebar scrollbar -->
    <div data-scrollbar="true" data-height="100%">
        <!-- begin sidebar user -->
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-profile">                
                <div class="info">
                        Matt Smith
                    <small>Manager</small>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end sidebar user -->
        <ul class="nav">
            <!-- begin sidebar minify button -->
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="sidebar-minify-btn" data-click="sidebar-minify"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a></li>
            <!-- end sidebar minify button -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end sidebar scrollbar -->
</div>
<!--sidebar left end-->
```

JavaScript

```
var handleSidebarMinify = function() {
    $('[data-click=sidebar-minify]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sidebarClass = 'page-sidebar-minified';
        var targetContainer = '#page-container';
        if ($(targetContainer).hasClass(sidebarClass)) {
            $(targetContainer).removeClass(sidebarClass);
            if ($(targetContainer).hasClass('page-sidebar-fixed')) {
                generateSlimScroll($('#sidebar [data-scrollbar="true"]'));
            }
        } else {
            $(targetContainer).addClass(sidebarClass);
            if ($(targetContainer).hasClass('page-sidebar-fixed')) {
                $('#sidebar [data-scrollbar="true"]').slimScroll({destroy: true});
                $('#sidebar [data-scrollbar="true"]').removeAttr('style');
            }
            // firefox bugfix
            $('#sidebar [data-scrollbar=true]').trigger('mouseover');
        }
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BootstrapOrBust/71og00ev/1/

Comment: Right at the top of your JS there's a reference to a "targetContainer" which has an id of "page-container". I don't see that in your provided HTML. Is that on your page? Nothing will work without that element.

Comment: Yeah I can't find it in my HTML, I wasn't sure what to replace it with, I tried the sidebar id but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not include jQuery library in your html. I've added check for JQuery at the top of your code:

```
alert(typeof jQuery !== "undefined")
```

it returns `false` that means you don't add JQuery. You can see the `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error on browser console. [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71og00ev/4/)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit confused, I don't think I need jQuery or I am using it here? So wouldn't it return false if I had a page that wasn't using jQuery?

Comment: Yup your JS is using jQuery objects, you need a jQuery library in your page.

Comment: You should include JQuery library in your HTML, or convert JQuery code to pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (without an animation) without any javascript at all, using the css's :hover.

EDIT: I just realised you wanted to control the expansion and collapse with buttons. This answer doesn't address that, but I'll leave it here anyway as an alternative.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2byg62z4/

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0; }

    #sidepanel
    {
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 30px;
        height: 60%;
        top: 20%;
        left: 0;
    }

    #bar
    {
        display: table;
        background-color: #999999;
        color: white;
        width: 30px;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #bar div
    {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #panel
    {
        display: none;
        background-color: #999999;
        color: white;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #panel div
    {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #sidepanel:hover #bar { display: none; }
    #sidepanel:hover #panel { display: table; }
</style>
<div id='sidepanel'>
    <div id='bar'>
        <div>
            &gt;<br>&gt;<br>&gt;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='panel'>
        <div>
            stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but I want it so the sidebar is displayed unless the user wants to collapse it. Thanks though.